# how to create a node.js script that can click a button on a external website starting that server

Tags: python, node.js, webserver

I am trying to build a discord bot that will take command to start a Minecraft server and click a button on a separate website to start the said server. The button clicking code runs from a python file but my bot is made in node.js. Is there a way I could create something that allows node.js to use the python file? I have started with python shell but can't get it to work.

**Node.js code:**

```
const { prefix } = require('config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = process.env.DISCORD_BOT_SECRET;
const aternosusername = process.env.ATERNOSUSERNAME;
const aternospassword = process.env.ATERNOSPASSWORD;
const keep_alive = require('./keep_alive.js')
var sleep = require('sleep'); 
//var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("I'm in");
  console.log(client.user.username);


});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'Start Server'){
    //PythonShell.run('serverstart.py', options, ClickStart() (err, results)) 
    msg.channel.send('Starting Please Wait.........');
    sleep.sleep(2);
    msg.channel.send('Server is now starting. This will take 5 to 8 mins.');
    ClickStart();
  }
});

async function ClickStart () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  await page.goto('https://aternos.org/go/');
  await page.authentication(credidentials);
  await page.click('#user');
  await page.keyboard.type('World', {delay: 100});
  await page.click('#password');
  await page.click('#login');
  console.log('Loging In');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.click('#start');
  console.log('Starting Server');

}



client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use npm module puppeteer to interact with ui

Steps:

```
npm install puppeteer --save
```

Then in your nodejs code do something like this

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.waitFor(1000);     //callibrate as per your need
  await page.goto('www.yourwebsite.com');
  await page.click('#yourButtonId');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
 })()
```

Look into [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) node module for further usage guidelines.

Comment: updated my answer as cheerio wasn't helpful in this case.

Comment: ok i have changed the code (posted above) and it works. is there a way to write text in a text box on a website with this code?

Comment: Yes you can. Try this::: await page.type('input[name=pickupAgingComment]', 'test comment', {delay: 20})